# Bind stored values to Combo box from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php code

```
<select class="form-control" name="txtNakshatra">
<?php
 $query = "SELECT * FROM MasterTable;
 $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<option value='" . $row['Id'] . "'>" . $row['Name'] . "</option>";
 }
?>
</select>
```

Which will Display all the details from the master table in a combo box.

Now I am inserting `$row['Id']` into `client` Table. So In `client` table I have stored the particular row value.

Now when I open the same page, I need to display the stored value in the Combo  box.

If I select `master_table_value_1` from the `listbox` for the first time which will have the `value` as `15` . the next time when I load the page, I need to display `master_table_value_1` in my Combo box.

How to do it? Any help appreciated

Comment: Store the value in a session. If it equals the current value give it the `selected` attribute.

Comment: Do you wants to show selected value in drop down ?

Comment: yeah i want to show the selected value